# Assembly resolution failure logging

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a custom framework my application is using to load assemblies on the fly (my application loads the assemblies instead of .NET, I know this sounds weird but it is a requirement :) ). 
The nice thing about letting .NET load assemblies is you get nice fusion log reports that you can read when something goes wrong. Is there a way to get such behavior when self loading assemblies (log assembly look up activity and failures into Fusion log) ?

Comment: Downvoter, can you please elaborate on the -1?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a handler of your own to the [AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and do whatever you want when it is raised. You can log or try another path or something.

Comment: Thanks. I am already doing this but this is not what I want :) I need to get the log statements to be seen by fusion log.